# How to render string with variables?

Tags: php

Unfortunatelly I keep part of HTML code in database and I have problem with rendering it with variables.

```
public function myFunction()
{
    //...
    // example data
    $data = array(
        'url' => 'example.com',
        'value' => 'Go to website!'
    );

    //Here I get html code from database, let's say it looks like this:
    $htmlPart = "<a href='{$data['url']}'>{$data['value']}</a>";

    $html = // rendered $htmlPart with variables

    return $html;
}
```

If I do:

```
echo $htmlPart;
```

inside my function. It works, but I need to return rendered **$htmlPart** as a variable, but I can't get it working.

I even tried to do it using **ob_start**:

```
ob_start();
echo $htmlPart
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

But it doesn't work, here it is what I get:

```
<a href="{$data['url']}">
    {$data['value']}
</a>
```

(this is rendered html I get in source code)

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you just concat the string with the var? ..the old fashioned way, you know?

Comment: So, you *literally* have `{$data['url']}` stored in your database and you want to replace it with its value?  You're going to need to parse the string (possibly using a regex) and replace the values.

Comment: If it's a literal string, how do we explain: "if I do `echo $htmlPart` inside my function it works".  OP can you confirm this? It actually outputs `href="example.com"` if you echo from within the function?

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php ?

Comment: @aynber: That'll probably work, but just be warned of the security issues of using `eval`.

Comment: Yes, I have literally `{$data['url']}` stored in my database

Comment: @user1409508: Then what *did* you mean by "If I do: `echo $htmlPart;` inside my function. It works"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I just checked again and it looks like I was wrong. It doesn't render even if I use echo inside function. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public function myFunction()
{
    //...
    // example data
    $data = array(
        'url' => 'example.com',
        'value' => 'Go to website!'
    );

    $htmlPart = "<a href='".$data['url']."'>".$data['value']."</a>"; // change to this

    $html = // rendered $htmlPart with variables

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: I think he *literally* has the string `{$data['url']}` saved in his database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a regex and `preg_replace_callback` to parse out the variables from the string and replace them with their values.

Something like this:

```
<?php    
$data = array(
    'url' => 'example.com',
    'value' => 'Go to website!'
);

//Here I get html code from database, let's say it looks like this:
// Single quotes so it's the *literal* text
$htmlPart = '<a href=\'{$data[\'url\']}\'>{$data[\'value\']}</a>';

// Double backslashes needed so the regex is correct
$html = preg_replace_callback("/\\{\\$(.*?)\\['(.*?)']}/", function($matches) use($data){
    return $data[$matches[2]];
}, $htmlPart);

echo $html;
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/607169